# How to use a copy-constructor in a LINQ to Entities query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I'm working on a `Linq` expression in which I get an object from a DBContext, and I want to make it a custom ViewModel object

my ViewModel receives as parameter an object obtained from the `DBContext` to work the information and return it completely

This is a little example

```
public class Obj1 // Object i get from database
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string Param { get; set; }
   public string Param2 { get; set; }
   public string Random { get; set; }
}

public class Obj2 //ViewModel
{
   public string ParamFormateado { get; set; }
   public string  Random { get; set; }

   public Obj2(Obj1 parametro)
   {
     ParamFormateado = parametro.Param + parametro.Param2;
     Random = parametro.Random;
   }

}
```

What I'm trying to do is get an `Obj2` with a Linq expression who returns an `Obj1` without transforming the information in the linq expression, since in my case it becomes a basically illegible expression

I was try something like this

```
Obj2 objeto = db.Obj1.Where(x => x.id == "0").Select(x => new Obj2(x)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is it possible to perform a `Linq` query similar to the one I am proposing? since otherwise, I end up having extremely long `Linq` expressions to format this information, but what would be the best alternative in these cases?

Comment: If you lay out your Linq queries, they become far more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that because only parameterless constructors are supported. But you can do it with `Linq-To-Objects` which can be forced with [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Obj2 objeto = db.Obj1
   .Where(x => x.id == "0")
   .AsEnumerable()   // <--- here
   .Select(x => new Obj2(x))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

So only the filter with `Where` will be executed in the database, the remaining record(s) are processed in-process.

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable/

Comment: can you explain how we can use where on an object? `db.Obj1
   .Where`

Comment: @Lucifer This is Entity Framework (check the question tags), `Obj1` is some sort of `DbSet`.

Comment: @Lucifer: i thought that this is the entity and just has the same name as the class. Otherwise i don't understand `db.Obj1`. It should have a plural in the name.

Comment: @DavidG I missed that.

Comment: You are amazing! thats exactly the solution!

Comment: To know, all the code before `AsEnumerable()` will be executed as SQL Query, and all after will be executed with `Linq-To-Objects`?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal: Yes. Read the link i've posted from J.Skeet

Answer (score 0):

Dont do it with Linq like that. you have to create a method that takes obj1 as parameter, maps properties and then returns obj2. Or use Automapper from nuget repository.

do it like this

```
public obj2 Map(obj1 source)
{
   var destination = new obj2();
   destination.param1 = source.param1;
   //
   return destination;
}
```

if you want to pass a collection of objects then do just that and just foreach through the list and return a list of mapped objects. But i would advise you to use Automapper since it automates the proces and you dont have to write a long mapping code.